# How to convert iphone iOS (NSDate) Timestamp using Python

Tags: python, ios, iphone, timestamp, converters

I have bunch of timestamps from consolidated.db on iphone 5 (ex 402102940.4584 ; 402259796.647231 ; 402373726.55571 and so on). 
I need using python get some meaning out of them. Is there any way I can translate them?

Comment: The big number recorded in the time stamp is the amount of time, in seconds, since January 1, 2001. So I got unix time-stamp for January 1, 2001 unixTS = 978307200 (GMT)(which is also in seconds). So that now date =  str(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(unixTS + iphoneTS)) works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried that, but 1982 timestamp for iphone 5 is not right. It is not unix format timestamp it is as I understand NSdate format which I dont know what I can do.

What found later: The big number recorded in the time stamp is the amount of time, in seconds, since January 1, 2001. So I got unix time-stamp for January 1, 2001 (GMT) (which is also in seconds). So that now:

```
>>>unixTS = 978307200 
>>>date = str(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(unixTS + iphoneTS))
```

Comment: Great answer, this an actual problem, question should not be closed in first place!

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this.

```
>>> d = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(402373726.55571)
datetime.datetime(1982, 10, 2, 10, 28, 46, 555710)
>>> str(d)
'1982-10-02 02:28:46.555710'
```

[How to convert NSDate into unix timestamp iphone sdk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2997062/how-to-convert-nsdate-into-unix-timestamp-iphone-sdk)

Comment: I tried that, but 1982 timestamp for iphone 5 is not right. It is not unix format timestamp it is as I understand NSdate format which I dont know what I can do.