# How to Convert a particular NSDate to UNIX time stamp in ios

Tags: iphone, ios7, ios6, nsdate, unix-timestamp

I want to convert my date Object to Unix time stamp.

```
  // "**strSellTime**"  has  the string of my date

 NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter=[NSDateFormatter new];

 [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEEE MMM yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss a"];

 NSDate *date=[dateFormatter dateFromString:strSellTime];
```

and wants to convert this date to UNIX time stamp like (1395382740) in this format.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert NSDate into unix timestamp iphone sdk?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2997062/how-to-convert-nsdate-into-unix-timestamp-iphone-sdk)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

time_t unixTime = (time_t) [date timeIntervalSince1970];

was able to solve it by this

Answer (score 2):

Just use
`[(NSDate*)date timeIntervalSince1970]`