# how to convert a date String like "05/20/2015 05:27 pm" into NSDate then to timestamp

Tags: ios, timestamp, nsdate

I am converting this date string `"05/20/2015 05:27 pm"` into `NSDate` with the help of formatter but it returns `nil`.

```
-(NSDate *)dateFromString:(NSString *)strDate withFormat:(NSString *)strDateFormat
{
NSDate *date = nil;

[self.dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];
if (strDate) {
    if (strDateFormat) {
        [self.dateFormatter setDateFormat:strDateFormat];

    }

    date = [self.dateFormatter dateFromString:strDate];

}
return  date;
}
```

I am using the above function where I am passing the string as `"05/20/2015 05:27 pm"` with format `@"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"`.

Comment: Please put your code here.

Comment: call you function like this : `[self dateFromString:@"05/20/2015 05:27 pm" withFormat:@"mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm a"]`

Answer (score 1):

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm a"];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];
NSDate *stringDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"05/20/2015 05:27 pm"];
NSLog(@"%@", stringDate);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
-(NSDate *)dateFromString:(NSString *)strDate withFormat:(NSString *)strDateFormat
{
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:strDateFormat];

    [dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];
    NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:strDate];
    return date;

}
```

Comment: there is no problem with the function, I am passing a wrong format . this format helps "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm a" given by @VD Patel

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *dateStr = @"05/20/2015 05:27 pm";

// Convert string to date object

NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss Z"];

NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateStr]; 

Nslog(@"%@",date);
```

Answer (score 0):

To transform from NSDate to timestamp you can use:

```
NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
NSTimeInterval timestampSeconds = [date timeIntervalSince1970];
```

Result will be in seconds. To transform timestamp to standard milliseconds just multiply by `1000`.

Answer (score 0):

[timeIntervalSince1970](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDate/timeIntervalSince1970)

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm a"];
NSDate *strDate = [formatter dateFromString:@"05/20/2015 05:27 pm"];
NSLog(@"%@", strDate);//NSDate
time_t timeStamp = (time_t) [strDate  timeIntervalSince1970];
NSLog(@"%ld", timeStamp);//timestamp
```

[How to convert NSDate into unix timestamp iphone sdk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2997062/how-to-convert-nsdate-into-unix-timestamp-iphone-sdk)

This might helps you :)