# How to get created date and last login user ios swift4 to firebase

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, swift4

```
let createAt = Auth.auth().currentUser?.metadata.creationDate
```

I want to convert this value so that i can store in the database.

Comment: Here you can find the answer -  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38174178/get-created-date-and-last-login-date-from-firuser-with-firebase-3

Comment: How do I convert these values ​​into string?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38168085/firebase-2-0-store-date-and-timezone